# EPPlus: How to add space in a cell value in C#

Tags: c#, export-to-excel, epplus, epplus-4

I am currently working in an export to Excel of a *hierarchical* grid using `EPPlus`. So *all* child rows should be displayed with padding (space). As shown below:

[image]

As shown in the above, you can see I have added four spaces before *Software*, *QA*, *Analyst*, etc.

I have used the below code to add space:

```
worksheet.cells[1, 1].value = "    Software";
```

But this doesn't seem to be the proper way to me. I have tried with `\t`, but that doesn't work.

Is there a better approach I can use here?

Answer (score 8):

Use `Style.Indent` like this:

```
ws.Cells["A4"].Style.Indent = 5;
```

Here is a reference for how it is done inside the actual Excel UI:

*[How to indent cell data in Excel 2010](http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-indent-cell-data-in-excel-2010/)*

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another way would be to use an Excel formula to pad left, like:

```
string str = "SampleString";
objWorksheet.Cells[3, 1].Formula = string.Format("=REPT(\" \",1)&\"{0}\"", str);
```

Or pad the string directly like

```
string str = "SampleString";
objWorksheet.Cells[2, 1].Value = str.PadLeft(str.Length + 1, ' ');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want padding on the left and right side,
you can also do this dynamically like this:

```
foreach (var cell in worksheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, 1])
{
    cell.Value = $"   {cell.Value}   ";
}
```

Just change the range.